# android process crash on adb with simple app, not sure what i'm doing wrong

Tags: android, sdk, crash, adb

```
package com.russell.saw;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class learnandroid extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

   Button landroid_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.landroid_button); {

       landroid_button.setOnClickListener(
               new View.OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    setContentView(R.layout.button);

                }
            });

   }
   Button back_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.back_button); {

       back_button.setOnClickListener(
               new View.OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    setContentView(R.layout.main);

                }
            });

   }
    }
}
```

i'm unsure of what is going wrong, it's just a simple learning tester app, with two buttons, going from one page to another, but i get a crash as soon as i run it on the phone.

Comment: Can you post the logcat output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Woah! You have your onClickListeners set up all wrong. You are calling `setContentView` in the onClickListeners. Instead, you need to use an intent to go from one activity to the next. It needs to look like this:

```
myButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Main.this, MyOtherActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    });
```

Also, don't use `landroid_button` to reference your button: that's just the XML ID of the resource. Instead you need to grab hold of your button by doing something like this:

```
   Button myLandroidButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.landroid_button)
```

Then when you set up the onClickListener, use that variable: `myLandroidButton` like `myLandroidButton.setOnClickListener` and so on..

Comment: I've tried adding the lines to the manifest, then it doesn't load at all, and i'm not getting anything on logcat when i run a debug.

Comment: I changed my answer after looking at your code. Also, pastebin your manifest and lemme see it.

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't added an activity tag to AndroidManifest.xml, you will need to do so:

```
<activity android:name="learnandroid" android:label="I am learning Android"></activity>
```

You need to do this for each activity (underneath the application tag).

Answer (score 0):

Although I doubt that this is causing the crash, your code has a serious problem. When you call `setContentView` inside `onClick` in your listeners, the buttons landroid_button and back_button are no longer valid. That is, they are objects that are no longer tied to a window. (If the new content views have "the same" buttons, they no longer have listeners.)